# Travel from UK to US (1 week) and Europe (1 week or less) and come back. What kind of Visa?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, europe

I am travelling to UK (Sheffield) from India for a short term study tour (3 months). During that time when I m in UK, I have to visit US for a week time and Europe (For a week again) and come back to UK. Is it possible on my 6 months short term student visa? or I have to take any other specific visa type? What is a multiple entry visa? Can my short term student visa be a multiple entry visa? 
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: A normal visitor is multi http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24373/multiple-entry-visa-to-uk-sponsored-visitor .

Comment: If you come on a short-term study visa, it's not clear. The [University of Strathclyde](http://www.strath.ac.uk/media/ps/sees/informationandadviceteam/Exchange_and_Study_Abroad_Student_Visa_Information.pdf) claims it is typically single but can be multi but [University of Edinburgh](http://www.ed.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.137765!/fileManager/Entry%20clearance%20as%20a%20Student%20Visitor.pdf) and [University of Warwick](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/study/international/immigration/othervisas/studentvisitor/) both claim if you apply overseas it's multi.

Comment: I can't find anything in [Immigration rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules) and [Short-term study visa](https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa) pages.

Comment: What is your nationality? I am not sure it makes a difference, but often it does in visa.

Answer (score 1):

> What is a multiple entry visa?

A multiple entry visa is a visa that lets you enter as many times as needed within its validity period. In contrast a single entry visa only lets you enter once and a double entry visa (not sure if the UK does this) only lets you enter twice.

It sounds like your travel plans would have you entering the UK three times so you would require a multiple entry visa for the UK.

You would also require appropriate visas for the USA and whatever parts of europe you plan to visit.

> Can my short term student visa be a multiple entry visa?

I don't know specifically about short term student visas. Other commenters have dug up information that indicates that it can be but might not ncessacerally be. So you should probablly include details of the trips to europe and america when applying for the visa.